# Creating a unique ID on from a mix of two fields on Access

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

I'm looking to create a unique ID that will come from a mix of two field. One field will be the name whilst the other will be just a random number.

For instance the name being 'Barry' and the number being '0001'. How do I do it so that a field will then look at these two fields and then generate 'Barry0001'?

Thanks

Comment: How will the records be created?  Via a form? A user typing directly into a table? Also, I assume the same name can appear multiple times, else already unique, therefore you need to be prepared for how to handle if your 'random' number just happens to repeat for another 'Barry'. If updating through a form, then easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO YourTable" _
    & "(YourNewFieldName, Title) VALUES " _
    & "('Name' & 'Number', 'Pop rock star');"
```

That's in VBA.

If you were doing this in QBE, your field name would look something like this:

```
Jim001: [NameField] & [NumberField]
```

Concatenation is compatible with Access 2013, Access 2010, Access 2007, Access 2003, Access XP, Access 2000.

Regular concatenation is done using the ampersand.